# Unexpected deque python behaviour

Tags: python, collections, deque

Why in the following assignment..

```
d = deque('abc')
a = d
d.clear()
print a
```

> > deque([])

returns a empty deque? I expect to retain data in **a** despite clearing the old deque.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a` and `d` reference the same object. So if you `clear` it, it will be cleared for "both variables".

You could check that by printing the identity of objects.

```
>>> id(a)
44988624L
>>> id(d)
44988624L
```

Copy values by assignment is just possible for fundamental data types like `int` etc.
If you deal with objects you have to copy it because the variables itself just holding a reference to the object.

You could do that with

```
d = deque('abc')
a = deque('abc')
```

or with

```
>>> import copy
>>> d = copy.copy(a)
```

which results in

```
>>> id(a)
44988624L
>>> id(d)
44989352L
```

but then you will get two different objects in `a` and `d` which will differ after you use it.

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
a = d
```

does not create a copy - it just creates another name for the same object.

To create a copy, do this:

```
d = deque('abc')
a = deque(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> d = deque('abc')
>>> a = deepcopy(d)
>>> d.clear()
>>> a
deque(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Or you can use `deque's` built-in **copy** function.

```
>>> d = deque('abc')
>>> a = d.__copy__
>>> a
<built-in method __copy__ of collections.deque object at 0x02437C70>
>>> a = d.__copy__()
>>> a
deque(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> d.clear()
>>> a
deque(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

---

You were giving reference to the same object thats why after clearing the `d` even `a` was getting cleared. For that you need to copy the `object d` to `a` using deepcopy. Which copies the object for you instead of referencing it

```
>>> id(a)
37976360
>>> id(d)
37976248
```